# Is it possible to create a slack datetime picker element?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I need my slack bot to support user input date and time, I know there is DatePicker which I can input a certain date. But I also need time, I am thinking to use a text field to just input string, but it's annoying that users have to deal with format stuff every time.
Is there a better way to do this? or is it possible to make a date time picker by myself?

edit:
Users might input any specific time, any hour or minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Slack API currently only provides a date picker, not not a datetime picker.

However, you can create a datetime picker yourself: Combine a [date picker](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements) element with a [static select menu](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#static_select) element that has all the time options and voila you have a datetime picker.

This would be easiest to be implemented in a [Modal](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals), since this allows a user to set values for multiple elements at the same time.

Here is an example with [block-kit](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Pick%20a%20date%20for%20the%20deadline.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22datepicker%22%2C%22initial_date%22%3A%221990-04-28%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20a%20date%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Pick%20a%20time%20for%20the%20deadline%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22static_select%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20an%20item%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2210%3A00%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2210%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2211%3A00%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2211%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2212%3A00%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2212%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2213%3A00%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2213%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2214%3A00%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2214%3A00%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D). Depending on the granularity of your time values you may want to generate the list of options programmatically.

And if you need to provide a more granular input, like down to the minute, then I would suggest to place two selects:

- First for the hour (00 - 23)
- Second for the minute (00 - 59)

Here is an updated [block-kit example](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Pick%20a%20date%20for%20the%20deadline.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22datepicker%22%2C%22initial_date%22%3A%221990-04-28%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20a%20date%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Pick%20the%20hour%20for%20the%20deadline%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22static_select%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20an%20item%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2210%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2211%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2212%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2213%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2214%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Pick%20the%20minute%20for%20the%20deadline%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22static_select%22%2C%22placeholder%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Select%20an%20item%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2210%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2211%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2212%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2213%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%2214%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D) on how this would look.

And here is a screenshot of the example:
[image]

Dito for seconds if you need them.

The maximum allowed number of options for a select element is 100, so this will work.

Comment: thanks, I never thought of this method, this would make things easier! but then I realize that the user could input any hours and minutes, it's unrealistic to provide every possible minute.

Comment: A amended the answer with regards to your added requirement for minutes.

Comment: You can use [select menu with external source](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#select).  to provide every single option of hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Slack now has a timepicker: https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#timepicker

The dropdown portion of this element groups time by the hour. The element also offers the ability for text input so that you can set a granular time (like 5:42 PM).

This can be used as an accessory or a standalone element. The documentation outlines how to use it as an accessory. To use it as an element, you'd place this into the "element" part of the block:

```
        {
            "type": "timepicker",
            "action_id": "some action id you define",
            "initial_time": "2020-10-09",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "This is a datepicker!",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
```

Comment: As of this comment the timepicker is still a Beta feature so your app can not be distributed with it.

Comment: The time picker is no longer a beta feature.