# Slack bot timepicker element?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Are there any good workarounds to achieve a **timepicker** via Slack blocks inside a larger form? It looks like I have a few options:

1) Let the user enter in time just via a textbox ("10:00am") - but this is prone to errors and not very user friendly

2) Create select elements for each of **hours**, **minutes**, **AM/PM** and let them just select each - less error prone but still not very user friendly

The biggest problem with #2 is you can't do it in a larger form, you can only do it inside an actions block (if you don't want the select boxes to all be 100% width).  But that doesn't work if your form submits via an option other than the action block button.  So for example, if you submit your form via a view submission action, you can't (I don't think) capture any of the data inside your nested action block. So you're stuck with 100% select boxes, or at least it seems impossible to put two select boxes on the same row inside a view.

Comment: You use an option list of hours and one for minutes.

Comment: @MarkGiblin yeah that's option #2 above. The problem there is if you use options lists inside a modal they're going to be 100% width. Or at least you can't put two selects side by side as far as I can tell (outside of an actions block).

Comment: I think this solution might work for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618607/is-it-possible-to-create-a-slack-datetime-picker-element/58753446#58753446

Comment: I have never experienced that issue, its down to what your main CSS styling would do to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a beta feature but you can use a time picker block.
example: [link](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T077TFZ2S#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22Section%20block%20with%20a%20timepicker%22%7D,%22accessory%22:%7B%22type%22:%22timepicker%22,%22initial_time%22:%2213:37%22,%22placeholder%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Select%20time%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22action_id%22:%22timepicker-action%22%7D%7D%5D%7D)

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Section block with a timepicker"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "timepicker",
                "initial_time": "13:37",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select time",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "action_id": "timepicker-action"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```